# Getting FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: TIMEOUT error while trying to get an instance ID

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying out a Firebase Cloud Messaging app on the lines of this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/

I have done all the config changes and coding as mentioned in the article. However, when I run my application, I see the below lines in the log:

> W/InstanceID/Rpc: No response android.os.ConditionVariable@da895ac
>
> D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: TIMEOUT, retry in 20s

I am not getting the Firebase Token. I have checked that NETWORK_PROVIDER is available. I am able to get maps and browse on my "Nexus 5X API 25 x86" emulator. The emulator has Google Play Services and is based on Google API.

Has anyone faced the TIMEOUT issue? How did you resolve it? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a workaround. Created a new emulator and it worked. Even though the new emulator is of same type, config etc of the earlier one, it seems to work with this new one. Not sure of the reason, though.